# Which application do I complete for a UK visitor visa for an 8-year old child?

Tags: uk

I need to apply for a UK visitor visa for an 8-year old. I see there is only one type of online form available on the UK.gov website. Do I fill out the same form as I did for my own standard visitor visa for my child? I know the visa fees are all the same regardless of age.